# Query to find late parts shipped and list them by quarter

Tags: sql, database

I am having the toughest time getting a query created for this scenario:

I need to list all parts that were late and sum them by quarter.

Here is the query that I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped],'\Qq yyyy') AS [Date_Shipped By Quarter]
,   Sum(InvoiceSub.Quantity) AS [Sum Of Quantity]
FROM 
    InvoiceSub 
    INNER JOIN 
        Job_Book_Sub 
        ON (InvoiceSub.[Job #] = Job_Book_Sub.[Job #]) 
        AND (InvoiceSub.[LineItem#] = Job_Book_Sub.[LineItem#])
GROUP BY 
    Format$([InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped],'\Qq yyyy')
,   Year([InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped]) * 4 + DatePart('q', [InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped]) -1;
```

This query works fine to display all parts that were shipped by quarter.  However, I want to see all parts that were shipped LATE by quarter.

I have a field in a table named: Job_Book_Sub, and that field is [LineItem_DueDate].  I want to use that in the query so that it will display all parts that were late ([date_shipped] > [lineitem_duedate]).  The [date_shipped] is the actual date the parts were shipped, [lineitem_duedate] is the date the parts were due.  I know that I need to incorporate these two fields into the query, I just don't know how.

Can someone please show me how to do this?  If I add the [LineItem_DueDate] to the query, then it no longer sums the dates by quarter but instead lists every record (so instead of having 45 records with different quarters over the past 10+ years, I all of a sudden have 13000+ records because it is listing each record with date_shipped in the query.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your filter in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped],'\Qq yyyy') AS [Date_Shipped By Quarter]
,   Sum(InvoiceSub.Quantity) AS [Sum Of Quantity]
FROM 
    InvoiceSub 
    INNER JOIN 
        Job_Book_Sub 
        ON (InvoiceSub.[Job #] = Job_Book_Sub.[Job #]) 
        AND (InvoiceSub.[LineItem#] = Job_Book_Sub.[LineItem#])
WHERE
    Job_Book_Sub.[date_shipped] > Job_Book_Sub.[lineitem_duedate]
GROUP BY 
    Format$([InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped],'\Qq yyyy')
,   Year([InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped]) * 4 + DatePart('q', [InvoiceSub].[Date_Shipped]) -1;
```